# Convert pandas dataframe to JSON schema

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "ID": [123123, 222222, 333333],
  "Main Authors": ["[Jim Allen, Tim H]", "[Rob Garder, Harry S, Tim H]", "[Wo Shu, Tee Ru, Fuu Wan, Gee Han]"],
  "Abstract": ["This is paper about hehe", "This paper is very nice", "Hello there paper from kellogs"],
  "paper IDs": ["[123768, 123123]", "[123432, 34345, 353545, 454545]", "[123123, 3433434, 55656655, 988899]"],
}
```

[image]

and I am trying to export it to a JSON schema. I do so via

```
df.to_json(orient='records')

'[{"ID":123123,"Main Authors":"[Jim Allen, Tim H]","Abstract":"This is paper about hehe","paper IDs":"[123768, 123123]"},
{"ID":222222,"Main Authors":"[Rob Garder, Harry S, Tim H]","Abstract":"This paper is very nice","paper IDs":"[123432, 34345, 353545, 454545]"},
{"ID":333333,"Main Authors":"[Wo Shu, Tee Ru, Fuu Wan, Gee Han]","Abstract":"Hello there paper from kellogs","paper IDs":"[123123, 3433434, 55656655, 988899]"}]'
```

but this is not in the right format for JSON. How can I get my output to look like this

```
{"ID": "123123", "Main Authors": ["Jim Allen", "Tim H"], "Abstract": "This is paper about hehe", "paper IDs": ["123768", "123123"]}
{and so on for paper 2...}
```

I can't find an easy way to achieve this schema with the basic functions.

Comment: On the contrary, Pandas produces valid JSON. What you ask is NOT valid JSON. There can only be a single root object in any JSON document, whether that's an object or an array.

Comment: The desired output isn't valid JSON but it's a common way to [stream JSON objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming). This is an old technique but many people tried to hijack it and present it as their own 'standard" resulting in a lot of names that mean the same non-standard thing: storing one unindented JSON object per line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_json` returns a proper JSON document. What you want is not a JSON document.

Add `lines=True` to the call:

```
df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)
```

The output you desire is *not* valid JSON. It's a very common way to stream JSON objects though: write one unindented JSON object per line.

[Streaming JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming) is an old technique, used to write JSON records to logs, send them over the network etc. There's no specification for this, but a lot of people tried to hijack it, even creating sites that mirrored Douglas Crockford's original JSON site, or mimicking the language of RFCs.

Streaming JSON formats are used a lot in IoT and event processing applications, where events will arrive over a long period of time.

PS: I remembered I saw a few months ago a question about `json-seq`. Seems there was an attempt to standardize streaming JSON [RFC 7464](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7464) as JSON Sequences, using the mime type `application/json-seq`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `DataFrame` to list of dictionaries first.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "ID": [123123, 222222, 333333],
  "Main Authors": [["Jim Allen", "Tim H"], ["Rob Garder", "Harry S", "Tim H"], ["Wo Shu", "Tee Ru", "Fuu Wan", "Gee Han"]],
  "Abstract": ["This is paper about hehe", "This paper is very nice", "Hello there paper from kellogs"],
  "paper IDs": [[123768, 123123], [123432, 34345, 353545, 454545], [123123, 3433434, 55656655, 988899]],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_dict('records')
```

The result:

```
[{'ID': 123123,
  'Main Authors': ['Jim Allen', 'Tim H'],
  'Abstract': 'This is paper about hehe',
  'paper IDs': [123768, 123123]},
 {'ID': 222222,
  'Main Authors': ['Rob Garder', 'Harry S', 'Tim H'],
  'Abstract': 'This paper is very nice',
  'paper IDs': [123432, 34345, 353545, 454545]},
 {'ID': 333333,
  'Main Authors': ['Wo Shu', 'Tee Ru', 'Fuu Wan', 'Gee Han'],
  'Abstract': 'Hello there paper from kellogs',
  'paper IDs': [123123, 3433434, 55656655, 988899]}]
```

Is that what you are looking for?